# Image format for glGenTextures

Tags: python, opengl

I have converted an image in python using

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('myPixelArt.bmp')
```

Then I call

`im = glGenTextures(1,img)`

But it turns out that `im = 0`

And many other functions

I have tried almost everything to display this image, and I would like to know that what I am putting into this function.

What is the format of the second argument in glGenTextures (not in terms of .bmp or.png but in terms of matrix size, whether the numbers range from 0 to 1 or up to 255 etc.)?

How do I find the format of img in python?

And is glGenTextures just supposed to return 0?

Comment: No, `glGenTextures (...)` is not supposed to return **0**. In C, it reserves n-many unused names and stores them in the array you pass (and does not return anything). Python's probably a little bit different, but the idea is the same. The name **0** is never _unused_; initially **0** is bound to all texture image units and we call it the "default" texture. The lowest number you will ever get from a successful call to `glGenTextures (...)` is **1**.

Comment: Thanks, then I think img is in the wrong form; I tried  im = glGenTextures(1)  and I get im =0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missunderstand what `glGenTextures` does. This function only create a Handler for an OpenGL Texture. You are using `c` language signature, which is only informative in python documentation.

This function returns `n` integer that will serve as name for your texture, the correct syntax in c is:

```
void glGenTextures(GLsizei n,  GLuint * textures);
```

But you are not using c, so for python, you have to use the correct signature:

```
 textures = glGenTextures   ( n )
```

where textures have to be an array that will hold the names returned by the function.

You may set n=1 for a single texture:

```
texture = glGenTextures(1)
```

To configure and set data's for your new texture you have then to bind a name to the context with `glBindTexture`, set the pixels data of your texture with `glTexImage2D` and also you may set some parameters with `glTexParameter`.

For a complete example see [here.](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/SimpleOpenGL2dClasses)

Comment: OP is using Python; there's no such thing as pointers, and the bindings will likely deviate from the standard function signature to compensate.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: Thanks, I've never programmed in Python.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: there was nothing wrong in my explanation, you may adapt your judgment...

Comment: @j-p Thanks. So in that case glGenTextures does not even do anything with img?

Comment: I'm not python programmer, but I can't find a concrete example with glGenTextures(param1,param2) even if in [that doc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGenTextures.html) it makes me think it's possible.

Comment: @j-p that example at the bottom of your answer is very useful to me, thanks